# change value of a column base on another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I got a set of data like this

```
name        rank    sub        id
7 ELEVEN    049     0001    2010490001
7 ELEVEN    049     0001    2010490001
7 ELEVEN    049     0001    2010490001
7 ELEVEN    049     0001    2010490001
7 ELEVEN    049     0001    2010490001
7 ELEVEN    192     0001    2011920001
7 ELEVEN    192     0001    2011920001
7 ELEVEN    999     4417    2019994417
AAR bus     047     0003    2010470003
AAR bus     050     0004    2010500004
```

the id formula is = 201 + rank + value. 
I want to check if the "name" column has the same value if so change the "rank" and "sub" column to the smallest value in that group name so that all "id" will be the same

Here 's what i want

```
name        rank    sub        id
7 ELEVEN    049     0001    2010490001
7 ELEVEN    049     0001    2010490001
7 ELEVEN    049     0001    2010490001
7 ELEVEN    049     0001    2010490001
7 ELEVEN    049     0001    2010490001
7 ELEVEN    049     0001    2010490001
7 ELEVEN    049     0001    2010490001
7 ELEVEN    049     0001    2010490001
AAR bus     047     0003    2010470003
AAR bus     047     0003    2010470003
```

Is there any way to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `min` with specifying columns in list and reassign back:

```
df[['rank','sub','id']] = df.groupby('name')['rank','sub','id'].transform('min')
print (df)
       name rank   sub          id
0  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
1  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
2  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
3  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
4  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
5  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
6  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
7  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
8   AAR bus  047  0003  2010470003
9   AAR bus  047  0003  2010470003
```

Or:

```
df[['rank','sub']] = df.groupby('name')['rank','sub'].transform('min')
df['id'] = '201' + df['rank'] + df['sub']
print (df)
       name rank   sub          id
0  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
1  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
2  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
3  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
4  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
5  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
6  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
7  7 ELEVEN  049  0001  2010490001
8   AAR bus  047  0003  2010470003
9   AAR bus  047  0003  2010470003
```

Comment: Thanks,the second way worked for me . The first way convert the "id" column to float type somehow

Answer (score 0):

You need to create groups with the minimal values `rank` and `sub` for each `name`, then replace the existing values with them, and re-create the `id`:

```
rank_mins = df[['name', 'rank']].groupby('name').min().reset_index()
sub_mins = df[['name', 'sub']].groupby('name').min().reset_index()
df = df.drop(['rank', 'sub'], axis=1).merge(rank_mins, how='left').merge(sub_mins, how='left')[['name', 'rank', 'sub', 'id']]
df['id'] = '201' + df['rank'] + df['sub']
```